# Send text field in multipart form data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have next code for uploading file with two accessors mode: private, share. Field "share" is text field that may be "true" or "false" values. By default, it value is false (process by server). But in my request, this field is bad param. 
So, how can i send raw string using Alamofire ?

```
func uploadFile(let URL: NSURL, let mode: Bool){
    self.showHUD()
    Alamofire.upload(.POST, Links.getApiURL(), multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if mode {

            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "true".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name: "share")
        }else{
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "false".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name: "share")
        }
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: URL, name: "file")



        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {

            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.hud.progress = Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead)
                    }
                    }.responseString { response in
                        self.hideHUD()
                        self.delegate?.childViewControllerResponse()
                        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                    }
            case .Failure( _):
                let viewAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Upload error", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                self.presentViewController(viewAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about alamofire, but as a side note, nsurlsession is really efficient. try it